# Como passar parâmetros para uma consulta num repositório?

Tags: java, sql, query, design-pattern, padrão-dao

Estou criando uma série de classes que retornam listagens em Java (Android).

Estou preocupado com o formato dos parâmetros que serão passados. Minha abordagem inicial tem sido passar um `Map` com parâmetros, dessa forma
eu posso adicionar ou remover parâmetros sem grandes alterações nas camadas.

```
public List<PlPg> getLista(SQLiteDatabase p_db,Map<String, Object> parametros)
```

Porém, o que tem se mostrado enjoativo é que sempre que vou chamar essa função eu preciso 'conferir' o nome das keys dos parâmetros que são usadas dentro da função.

```
// Aqui eu pego os parâmetros do map.
int pzmax = (Integer)parametros.get("pzmax");
int cliente = (Integer)parametros.get("cliente")

// Mas aqui, na hora de gerar o Map de parâmetros preciso conhecer as keys .
Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parametros.put("pzmax", p_pzmax);
parametros.put("cliente", p_cliente);
parametros.put("plpgpadrao", p_plano);
```

Minha ideia alternativa seria, receber - ao invés de um `Map` - um objeto que tenha os métodos que me retorne os valores dos filtros.

```
public List<PlPg> getLista(SQLiteDatabase p_db,IFiltroPlpg pFiltro);

//Essa seria interface q retorna os dados dos filtros
public interface IFiltroPlpg  {

    int pzmax();    
    int cliente();
    int planoPadrao();

}
```

Porém, com essa abordagem, eu preciso criar uma classe pra filtro pra cada configuração de listagem, com getters diferentes.

Gostaria de saber qual dessas abordagens seria a mais correta do ponto de vista de melhores práticas de POO, ou se existem outras opções melhores que essa.

Comment: Qual é a linguagem, jovem? Aliás, sua pergunta é apenas para pedir nossa opinião sobre a solução?

Comment: É só opinião mesmo, eu quero entender qual é menos penoso ( poderia ser java) 
Obrigado.

Comment: Ou talvez uma terceira opção tbm  =)

Comment: É complicado porque isso não faz parte do escopo do site (veja em [help/on-topic]).

Comment: Entendo, eu imaginei que entraria em algum conceito com melhores práticas em POO ...
De qualquer forma, obrigado

Comment: De qualquer forma, eu acho que sua pergunta tem salvação. Você precisa editá-la e ser mais específico, ao invés de pedir opiniões, peça alternativas concretas de como fazer. Trace um objetivo, explique onde quer chegar, até onde já foi e quais são as dúvidas que você tem. Seja claro, sucinto e pouco prolixo. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta a qualquer momento. Se melhorá-la, e eu achar que realmente mudou algo, retiro meu voto pra fechar.